# Qt control OSM location from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, openstreetmap

In my Qt5.9 widget application project (Windows), I added a QQuickWidget in the ui and set the source file to a QML file.

My itention is to display open street maps in the QQuickWidget. By clicking a button, the center location of the map should change to specific lat/long coordinates.

The map gets displayed in the QQuickWidget as expected, however, I can't get the location change by button click to work.

I am using this QML file content to display the map:

```
//================================
// map.qml
//================================
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {
    id: qmlMap

    Plugin {
        id: osmPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
        zoomLevel: 10
        objectName: "mainMap"

    MapQuickItem {
      id: marker
      coordinate {latitude: 59.91
                 longitude: 10.75}
      anchorPoint.x: image.width * 0.5
      anchorPoint.y: image.height

      sourceItem: Image {
         id: image
         height: 35
         width: 35
         source: "geotag.png"
      }
            function recenter(lat,lng) {
                  map.clearMapItems();
                  marker.coordinate.latitude = lat;
                  marker.coordinate.longitude = lng;
                  map.addMapItem(marker);
                  map.center.latitude = lat;
                  map.center.longitude = lng;
                  map.update();
            }
    }
    }
}
```

On application start up, I can see the OSM centered on my specified location and I also can see the marker at the right location.

[Loaded map on start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQijX.png)

However, when I click my button to call the function `recenter(lat,lng)` from C++, nothing seems to happen (no location change on map visible).

My C++ button code for location change is:

```
void mapproject::on_btnUpdatePos_clicked()
{
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, "qrc:/map.qml");
    QObject *object = component.create();

    QVariant returnedValue;
    QVariant pos = QVariant(0);

    if(object != NULL){
       QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "recenter",
       Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
       Q_ARG(QVariant, pos),
       Q_ARG(QVariant, pos));
    }
}
```

Why does the location change not work? Is there a mistake in my QML file or in my C++ code?

Comment: Why do you pass the coordinate 0, 0? Have you tried other coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I also tried other coordinates, beside 0, 0. However I didn't see a different behavoir. Creating the component in the button function was just for testing. My plan was to relocate it outside the function, when the location change works.

Comment: main.qml or map.qml? it confuses me to have 2 names for qml

Comment: sorry, I changed main.qml to map.qml

Comment: Show how it loads the map.qml to QQuickWidget

Comment: I attached an image of the initial map on start up.

Comment: I do not want to see that image, I want to see how to set the .qml to QQuickWidget through the setSource method.

Comment: I didn't use setSource. I added the QQuickWidget in Qt designer and set the source in the Qt designer gui.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `QQuickWidget` has been added through Qt Designer and it is called `quickWidget`, so you can access it using `ui->quickWidget`.

To do a simple search you can set an objectName in the MapQuickItem:

```
MapQuickItem {
    id: marker
    objectName: "mapItem"
    coordinate {latitude: 59.91
    [...]
```

You should not create a new component, you should use the `QQuickWidget`, the first thing is to get the item that shows the `QQuickWidget` through the `rootObject()` method, then look for the child named `mapItem` and invoke the recenter method:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnUpdatePos_clicked()
{
    QQuickItem *item = ui->quickWidget->rootObject();
    QObject *object = item->findChild<QObject*>("mapItem");
    QVariant posx = QVariant(-12.0464);
    QVariant posy = QVariant(-77.0428);

    if(object != NULL){
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "recenter",
                                  Q_ARG(QVariant, posx),
                                  Q_ARG(QVariant, posy));
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48207970)

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this working example. I got it to work in my project.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am trying to implement your code however I keep getting a seg fault at ```QObject *object = item->findChild<QObject*>("mapItem");```. Im guessing that it couldnt find the object or something, what should i do?